# Как импортировать PDF в таблицу с колонкой BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

Возник вопрос, как проще всего импортировать  PDF в колонку`BLOB`?

Думал реализовать такую логику : импортировать `BLOB` во временную таблицу (процедурой ниже), а потом, чтобы добавить `BLOB` в поле исходной таблицы сделать что-то такое:

```
UPDATE My_table SET blob=(select blob_pdf from temp_table) where rownum=1;
```

Пробовал следующим образом, но как по мне это слишком костыльно. И как оказалось, на работе нет прав на создание директории (1-ая строка). Сам скрипт:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY BLOB_DIR AS 'C:\\';

CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id        NUMBER,
  blob_data BLOB
);


DECLARE
  l_bfile  BFILE;
  l_blob   BLOB;

  l_dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
  l_src_offset  INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tab1 (id, blob_data)
  VALUES (1, empty_blob())
  RETURN blob_data INTO l_blob;

  l_bfile := BFILENAME('BLOB_DIR', 'smth.pdf');
  DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
  -- loadfromfile deprecated.
  -- DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.loadblobfromfile (
    dest_lob    => l_blob,
    src_bfile   => l_bfile,
    amount      => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
    dest_offset => l_dest_offset,
    src_offset  => l_src_offset);
  DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо вставить или изменить только небольшое кол-во записей из файлов на локальной файловой системе, то проще воспользоваться SQL Developer (поставляется в "коробке").

Выберите в проводнике слева ранее созданую таблицу, в примере:

```
create table tblob (id number, memo varchar2 (64), doc blob);
```

И далее, при добавлении или изменении записей, редактируйте значения `BLOB` колонки в диалоговом окне - *Edit Value*. Последовательность действий и назначение кнопок интуитивно и не нуждается в отдельном пояснении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После фиксации изменений кнопкой <kbd>F11</kbd>, в окне сообщений появятся лог произведённых изменений:

```
INSERT INTO "SH"."TBLOB" (ID, MEMO, DOC) VALUES ('1', 'Man. load', empty_blob())
UPDATE "SH"."TBLOB" SET DOC=? WHERE ROWID=:sqldevrowid AND ORA_ROWSCN=:sqldevrowscn

Commit Successful
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо! А кстати не подскажите, как прикрутить расширение File type в SQL Developer ? После заливки, к примеру, документа с расширением .pdf, он в БД после коммита лежит в формате .jpg...

Comment: @Garamoff Вы Вы что-то сделали не так. SQL Developer не преобразует файлы. На скрине же видно, File type: выбрать *.pdf, всё вроде. У вас там "View As: [ ]" не отмечены случаем?

Comment: Как раз в поле File Type пусто. Не стоит там никакого расширения, и как я понимаю, из-за этого ставится дефолтное какое-то. Читал где-то, что есть export.sql и следует в нем поковыряться, но думаю должно быть более простое решение проблемы. Скрин, к сожалению, сюда не могу добавить

Comment: А где вы видите в каком формате он лежит в БД? После загрузки это чисто бинарные данные без всяких расширений.

Comment: Да, понятно, что это бинарник. Просто при запросе документа в соап ответе возвращается токен с  файлом, имеющим расширением jpg вместо pdf-ника. По остальным документам возвращается корректно pdf

Comment: Значит у вас один файл был JPG.  БД не занимается преобразованием бинарных данных, она их только хранит. После выгругрузки в результате запроса, в клиенте определяется формат по цифровой подиси в файле. Какое было расширение в оригинальном файле, никто не знает, эта информация не сохраняется.

Comment: Да, вспомнил, как с полем "File Type: [ ]". В поле "File Name: [ ]" наберите: *.pdf и Ентер.  Ну как уже говорил, это облегчит поиск для выбора файла для загрузки по расширению, с собственно типом загружаемых данных это поле ничего обшего не имеет.

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо! Да, понятно

Answer (score 3):

У Oracle не очень хорошо со встроенными средствами загрузки BLOB. На сервере можно напрямую читать файлы с диска. Единственное ограничение это необходимость создания объектов `DIRECTORY`, большинстово админов (с которыми я общался) считают это угрозой беспоастности.
Сами функции по загрузке в какой-то степени будут похожи на представленную.

Чаще загружать файлы требуется с клиента, и если не хочется писать отдельную прогу (что правильно), то единственый способ использовать `SQL*Loader`. Почему то редко пишут, что `SQL*Loader` умеет это делать, хотя можно грузить как один файл, так и пачкой.

Примерные шаги по загрузке списка файлов.

**Создаем таблицу**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
  (id        NUMBER,
   author    VARCHAR2(30),
   created   DATE,
   text      CLOB
);
```

**Имеем два файла**

```
file1.txt: Тестовый файл
file2.txt: Еще один файл
```

**Создаем файл с описание (control file)**

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'loader.csv'
  INTO TABLE my_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ( id         CHAR(10),
    author     CHAR(30),
    created    DATE "YYYY-MM-DD" ":created",
    fname      FILLER CHAR(80),
    text       LOBFILE(fname) TERMINATED BY EOF
  )
```

**Файл `loader.csv` содержит как поля, так и путь к файл**у

```
1,John Smith,2015-04-29,file1.txt
2,Pete Jones,2013-01-31,file2.txt
```

**Запускаем**

```
sqlldr roger/roger control=loader.ctl log=loader.log bad=loader.bad
```

Пишу по памяти, могут быть ошибки.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я в итоге решил воспользоваться встроенными возможностями SQL Developer, дабы не выбивать права на доступы у админов :)

Answer (score 3):

> как оказалось на работе нет прав на создание директории

Создавать директорию не обязательно. Посмотреть доступные директории можно запросом:

```
select * from all_directories;
```

Если таковых нет, или нет прав на перенос файлов в эти директории на системном уровне, то вам запрещено загружать с файловой системы сервера. В этом случае, лучше обратиться к администраторам БД, чем искать обходные пути этого запрета.

Если подходящая директория есть, обычно `DATA_PUMP_DIR`, то подход как в вопросе вполне стандартный и рекомендуемый.

Можно даже немного "приукрасить", например:

```sql
create or replace function blobLoader (filename varchar2) return blob is
    bf bfile := bfilename ('TEMPFILES', filename);
    bl blob;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary (bl, true);
    dbms_lob.fileopen (bf, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
    dbms_lob.loadfromfile (bl, bf, dbms_lob.getlength (bf));
    dbms_lob.fileclose (bf);
    return bl;
end;
/

create table tblob (id number, memo varchar2 (64), doc blob);

insert into tblob values (1, 'test blob load', blobLoader ('test.pdf'));

1 row inserted.
```

Результат:

```
select memo, dbms_lob.getlength (doc) bloblen from tblob t;

MEMO                BLOBLEN
---------------- ----------
test blob load       300877
```

---

Альтернативный путь, загружать с локальной файловой системы [используя SQL*Loader](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1106559/217579).
Здесь только ссылка на оф. документацию, т.к. ответ с примером дал [@Alex R.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1106559/217579).

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо за ответ! Решил все-таки использовать SQL Developer для импорта

Comment: Это смотря с какой целью и в каком обьёме грузить. Несомненно, если потребуется масовая загрузка, то у вас из этого  ответа уже есть рабочее решение.