# Как загрузить данные из CSV файла в БД через SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle12c, datagrip

Есть **большой** CSV файл с таблицей, которую нужно загрузить в БД.

Для этого пишу в DataGrip SQL скрипт, но не знаю даже с чего начать.

Comment: Извините за уточнение, а какое ограничение накладывает DataGrip для решения вашей задачи?

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать нативный импорт в ДатаГрип?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чисто SQL решение, [создать внешнию таблицу (*External Tables*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E) и загружать из неё данные в целевые таблицы.

Допустим, есть CSV файл `params.csv` такой структуры:

```
1;key1;val1
2;key2;val2
3;key3;val3
```

Поместите его в доступный каталог на БД сервере, например `/tmp/extfiles/`, и создайте (если ещё не существует) объект директории:

```
create or replace directory extfiles as '/tmp/extfiles';
```

Теперь можно создать таблицу (см. [описание параметров](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil&id=SQLRF-GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)):

```
create table tabext1 (id number, key varchar2 (8), val varchar2 (16))
    organization external (
        default directory extfiles 
        access parameters (fields terminated by ";")
        location ('params.csv'));
```

И далее, обращаться к ней SQL запросами как к обычной таблице:

```
select * from tabext1;

        ID KEY      VAL             
---------- -------- ----------------
         1 key1     val1            
         2 key2     val2            
         3 key3     val3
```

---

**На заметку**:
В основном существует два способа загрузить CSV файлы в таблицы: *External Tables* и *SQL*Loader*. Для правильного выбора одного критерия: ***большой CSV файл***, недостаточно.
Ознакомтесь с разделом: [Behavior Differences Between SQL*Loader and External Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-AC0DBDB3-BD68-45A4-ABA3-3DE38BB038ED).

Comment: мне кажется стоит упомянуть о том, что директории можно создавать только на нодах сервера...

Comment: @MaxU Подожду уточнения ТС на комментарий под вопросом.

Comment: по-моему, это будет в любом случае полезно для тех, кто попадет сюда по ссылкам поисковиков

Answer (score 0):

В этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1106559/365777) я рассказывал про `SQL*Loader`, через него можно загрузить файл с данными.

Comment: Первое, я указал же вроде 12ю версию

Comment: И второе, я работую через DataGrip

Comment: А в 12 версии разве нет `SQL*Loader`? Про DataGrip я видел. Просто SQL*Loader - это самый быстрый способ загружать большие объемы данных. Может пригодится на будущее.