# Как проверить на наличие в таблице большого количества значений из списка?

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть список из 1000 номеров.

Как можно найти в таблице все записи, которые имеют номер в списке?

Мой список: `(0156556,8787856...)`
Ожидаю увидеть:

| Name | number |
| --- | --- |
| Ольга | 0156556 |
| Виктория | 8787856 |

Можно, конечно, сделать:

```
select name, number 
from base 
where number  in ('0156556','8787856', ...)
```

Но для большого списка это выглядит не очень эффективно.

Задача усложняется тем, что номера могут быть записаны с дополнительными символами, например:

| Name | number |
| --- | --- |
| Ольга | 01-56-556 |
| Виктория | 8787856 |

И вроде с регулярным выражением все делается просто:

```
select name, number 
from base 
where  REGEXP_LIKE (number, (0-?1-?5-?6-?5-?5-?6-?)|(8-?7-?8-?7-?8-?5-?6-?))
```

, но не писать же через OR  '|' все 1000 значений.

Comment: Ну вариантов-то навскидку всего два. Первый - оставить как есть (по-моему, Oracle сортирует такой список), второй - слить этот список во временную таблицу, индексировать и использовать в запросе.

Comment: дополню комментарий от @Akina - второй вариант с временной таблицей или со внешней, если у вас есть возможность скопировать CSV файл на сервер, на котором работает Oracle DB. По поводу регулярных выражений - можно написать функцию для нормализации номеров и создать ["function-based" индекс](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes). Возможно __0xdb__ или __Akina__ смогут написать полноценный ответ с примером)

Comment: _У меня есть список из 1000 номеров_, а где находится этот список и в каком он виде (формате)? Можете ли вы изменять таблицу, создавать индексы, функции  и т.д.?

Comment: @0xdb  тип number в списке, в oracle nvarchar2, находится в excel файле. Да могу изменять таблицу, создавать функции и т.д.

Comment: @JuliaKovalchuk Надо сначало загрузить список в БД, т.к. подозреваю, что вы начнёте упираться в лимиты инструментов, которые вы используете., чтобы передать список в БД как символьную строку. Самое простое, с внешними таблицами, как например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1111575/217579). Какая версия БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ниже воспроизводимый пример самого простого, по моему мнению, решения.

Символьные номера в таблице лучше сразу привести к числам. Добавте виртуальную колонку и индекс по ней:

```
create table nums (name, num) as
    select 'name '||rownum, trim (column_value) 
    from xmlTable ('"01-56-556","8787856","0156557","87-87-857"')
/
alter table nums add (normnum number invisible as (replace (num, '-'))) 
/
create index idx_nums on nums (normnum)
/
```

Создайте в директории, доступной для чтения из БД (в примере extfiles -> /tmp/extfiles), текстовый файл импортированный из Excel. Для примера создал его вручную:

```
$ echo "0156556,8787856"|tr , '\n' >/tmp/extfiles/listnum.dat
```

Следующий запрос даст ожидаемый результат:

```
with listnum as (
    select num 
    from external ((num number) 
        type oracle_loader default directory extfiles
        access parameters (records delimited by newline)
        location ('listnum.dat'))) 
select n.name, to_char (n.normnum, '0999999') num
from nums n join listnum l on l.num = n.normnum 
/

NAME     NUM     
-------- --------
name 1    0156556
name 2    8787856
```

---

Для версий старше 18c объявление внешних таблиц прямо в SQL запросе (*inline*) было недоступно. Необходимо создать внешнюю таблицу. Тот же результат, как выше, будет получен:

```
create table listnum (num number) organization external (
    type oracle_loader default directory extfiles
    access parameters (records delimited by newline)
    location ('listnum.dat'))
/
select n.name, to_char (n.normnum, '0999999') num
from nums n join listnum l on l.num = n.normnum 
/
```